# POST request doesn't work with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to do a post request on a page called Expression.cshtml with AngularJS:

```
$http.post('templates/Expression.cshtml', { data: $scope.elements[key]['expression'] });
```

It works well as you can see :

[image]

The problem is i can't get "data" parameter on Expression.cshtml , I have tried many things such as

```
@{

    dynamic expression = "";
    foreach (string name in Request.Form)
    {
    expression+=name;
    }
}
@expression
```

Or

```
@{

dynamic expression = "";
string expression = Request.Form["data"]    
}
@expression
```

And a lot of other things, but the problem is i've always an empty answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot POST to a page, you can POST to an action method in a controller. Actually, you are posting to a view, that makes even less sense :)

[ASP.NET MVC - Using Post, Redirect, Get Pattern](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/aspnet-mvc---using-post2c-redirect2c-get-pattern.aspx)

You should start with some ASP.NET tutorials like: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started to understand how ASP.NET MVC works.